# Minimum focus style for a text input

Tags: forms, accessibility

I'm currently working on a chat style UI that has a single text input for entering a message.

Usually I would follow the recommended accessibility best practises for the correct focus styling. I know a thick, contrasting outline focus style will have some push back within my company as the opinions will be that it looks a bit overpowering (not my opinion).

Is it ever ok to have a a blinking cursor as the minimum focus style on a textfield?  And then have a more contrasting focus-visible style?

As I understand it, it isn't but through my research I have seen countless examples of this, even from really large tech companies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you may be referring to is Discord, which with mouse input looks like this:

[image: input box with blinking cursor]

However, as soon as the user hits <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or otherwise engages the focus via keyboard, an accessible focus state is shown:

[image: input box with blinking cursor and blue outline]

---

The important bit is that people in need of these styles can access them quickly and easily. Hiding them behind a setting would not work as the people in question would not be able to access the setting in the first place, but from what I can tell, this particular pattern doesn't run into any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be ok under certain circumstances, if you want to achieve conformance level AA. For AAA, it’s impossible.

First of all, [WCAG’s Understanding Focus Visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html#sufficient)  requires:

> Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible.

The key here is *mode of operation*, which means you COULD make these focus styles a user setting. But you’d be surprised how many users do use the keyboard in forms, especially in enterprise software.

If the setting needs to be switched on, the controls to do so need to already use that visible focus, as they would be impossible to find for users who require that setting.

A best practice is to use something like [`:focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) for styling, so the outline is only visible when the user actually uses the keyboard (or similar input devices) to set focus on the input.

Further, the WCAG also lists the following sufficient technique for Focus Visible:

#### [G165](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/general/G165.html) Using the default focus indicator for the platform so that high visibility default focus indicators will carry over

In this case, you can refer to the platform as an excuse. The technique also mentions:

> The default rendering of the focus indicator isn't always highly visible […] However, many platforms allow the user to customize the rendering of this focus indicator.

Completely [hiding the focus indicator](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/failures/F78.html) with `:focus {outline: none}` will fail the success criterion. In the mentioned example, the cursor is still visible in inputs, but the WCAG are quite clear about that.

[Focus Appearance (Level AAA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/focus-appearance.html) does not leave any doubt and requires the control’s perimeter to be styled with enough contrast.